# Multiple nested where clauses in ravendb

Tags: ravendb

I'm trying to migrate this query from EF to ravendb

```
DateTime interval;
IList<string> excludedUserNames;

return this.ravenSession.Query<User>()
    .Where(u => 
        u.NotifyOnNewForumPost 
        && (u.LastForumsNotification < u.LastVisit || u.LastForumsNotification < interval))
    .Select(u => u.Email)
    .ToList();
```

using Query there seems to be no way to express the nested clauses, so I looked at DocumentQuery, but apparently lucene does not support comparing two values in a document.

Did I miss something in the documentation (It seems to handle only simple filtering?!), or is there another way to this (besides filtering in memory)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compare two values in RavenDB during query. The reason you cannot do that is that this requires the database engine to scan through all the documents to find matches.
Instead, create an index that would do the comparisons at indexing time, and query on the result of that.

Answer (score 0):

The `.Contains(u.UserName)` is not supported by Raven. You might be able to use a `.In(...)` instead:

```
return this.ravenSession.Query<User>()
    .Where(u => 
        u.NotifyOnNewForumPost 
        && (u.LastForumsNotification < u.LastVisit || u.LastForumsNotification < interval) 
        && !u.UserName.In(excludedUserNames))
    .Select(u => u.Email)
    .ToList();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that is an issue too, figured that out already. The issue with the where clauses remains unfortunately. I will update the question to avoid any confusion.

Comment: That kind of query should work. What is the error you're getting?